# paralleizing loops calling multiple functions

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a time consuming `for` loop in python. The `for` loop generates some indexes and then there are nested `for` loops and a function is called and an array is updated with the function return value. So, my naive code is implemented something as follows:

```
import numpy as np
N = 256
max_k = 32
g = np.zeros(N, N, N)
k = np.zeros(N, N, N)

# These will be used to generate some indexes and sampling points
ix = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
iy = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
iz = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)

kx = np.linspace(-max_k, max_k, N)
ky = np.linspace(-max_k, max_k, N)
kz = np.linspace(-max_k, max_k, N)

for idz, zi, zf in zip(count(), iz, kz):
    for idy, yi, yf in zip(count(), iy, ky):
        for idx, xi, xf in zip(count(), ix, kx):
            g[idx, idy, idz] = func1([[xi, yi, zi]])
            k[idx, idy, idz] = func2([[xf, yf, zf]])
```

So basically I have these nested loops and I am calling two functions and updating the values in the arrays. I see that there is a `multiprocessing Pool` class but I was not able to figure out how to map my loop body to get it to work with it especially how to generate these indexes to be able to use it with the Pool map method.

Comment: Create a multiprocessing Pool and use apply_async(your_func) and at the end close the pool, and wait until the threads are done with join.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I share the g and k arrays between the pool processes?

Comment: The arrays are visible to the functions called with apply_async. But for g and k it does not make sense, since you cannot see the modifications you make during the asynchronous calls.

Comment: Note that res=apply_async(...) returns an object. You can get the actual result to store in g and k by calling res.get() after the threads are done. So you might need to iterate over your input arrays twice.

Comment: @phobix I thought of that but each function call is updating one entry in the array. I do not know where can I catch this return value?

Comment: You can just store the results in a dict. As key you can use the tuple (idx, idy, idz), then you iterate over the dictionary keys, unpacking the tuple into the single variables again and can store it g[idx, idy, idz] = result_dict[(idx, idy, idz)].get().